# Как приостановить поток по запрету/позволению другого потока?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Требуется такой инструмент синхронизации потоков, который умеет следующее:

- Может быть создан в любом потоке.
- При вызове метода `wait` приостанавливал бы текущий поток, если ранее в любом потоке был вызван метод `take`.
- При вызове метода `wait` не делал бы ничего, если ранее в любом потоке был вызван метод `release`.
- Счетчик вызовов `take` и `release` не требуется.

В документации по Qt видел следующие инструменты синхронизации потоков: `QMutex`, `QSemaphore`, `QWaitCondition`. Не подходят. В `QWaitCondition` каждый раз требуется вызывать метод `wake`, иначе при вызове `wait` программа продолжит выполнение только один раз, а надо, чтобы поток продолжал выполнение до тех пор, пока не был вызван метод, которого там нет...

Comment: А чем Mutex не подходит? Замените wait на take + release.

Comment: а какую задачу пытаетесь решить? Сделать возможность ставить поток на паузу? Можно завернуть QWaitCondition  в собственный враппер.

Comment: @KoVadim, нужно действительно поставить поток на паузу, но нельзя делать это в произвольном месте, а только там, где вызывается метод `wait`.

Comment: @VladD, вы имеете в виду, что целевой поток блокирует мютекс и сразу освобождает? Я об этом не подумал.

Comment: @maestro: Ага, вроде ж вам нужно именно это по описанию?

Comment: Всё верно, должно сработать. Завтра проверю.

Comment: самый простой способ (не говорю, что самый правильный) - нужна одна атомик переменная (или прикрыта мютексом). Функции take/release теперь просто будут менять состояние этой переменной. А метод wait просто проверяет переменную и вызывает sleep(1s), если нужно. В будущем sleep будет заменен на обычный QWaitCondition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с блокировкой/разблокировкой мютекса не сразу удался, потому что в Qt нельзя вызывать метод `unlock` несколько раз подряд. Поэтому пришлось ввести флаг состояния. Всё вместе обернул в такой класс:

semaphorebinary.h:

```
#ifndef SEMAPHOREBINARY_H
#define SEMAPHOREBINARY_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMutex>

class SemaphoreBinary : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SemaphoreBinary(QObject *parent = 0);

    explicit SemaphoreBinary(bool taken, QObject *parent = 0);

    void wait();

    void take();

    void release();

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QMutex suspendMutex;
    QMutex stoppedMutex;
    bool stopped;
};

#endif // SEMAPHOREBINARY_H
```

semaphorebinary.cpp:

```
#include "semaphorebinary.h"

SemaphoreBinary::SemaphoreBinary(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    stopped(false)
{

}

SemaphoreBinary::SemaphoreBinary(bool taken, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    stopped(taken)
{

}

void SemaphoreBinary::wait()
{
    stoppedMutex.lock();
    if (stopped)
    {
        stoppedMutex.unlock();
        suspendMutex.lock();
        suspendMutex.unlock();
        return;
    }
    stoppedMutex.unlock();
}

void SemaphoreBinary::take()
{
    stoppedMutex.lock();
    if (!stopped)
    {
        stopped = true;
        stoppedMutex.unlock();
        suspendMutex.lock();
        return;
    }
    stoppedMutex.unlock();
}

void SemaphoreBinary::release()
{
    stoppedMutex.lock();
    if (stopped)
    {
        stopped = false;
        stoppedMutex.unlock();
        suspendMutex.unlock();
        return;
    }
    stoppedMutex.unlock();
}
```